# Recommended paging file size formula

Tags: virtual-memory

Is there a formula by which Windows calculates recommended paging file size? (see picture).
This is definitely not 1,5 x RAM (this PC has 8 GB or RAM).
I need to implement this calculation in my custom software, but can't seem to understand where Windows gets this value from.

Thanks!

[image: Recommended size]

Comment: @Hannu Disabling pagefile is [a bad idea in general](http://azius.com/blog/pagefile-yes1/).

Comment: Has it always been 8GB? I find when RAM is added that the paging file size is not adjusted.

Comment: Yes, it always had 8 GB.

Comment: @gronostaj - **agreed**! _Removed the comment, rephrased here_:  Generally, duplicating functionality is a bad idea. With abundance of RAM the system generally does not use much Vmem. With small amounts of RAM the need for Vmem rises, but there also is a penalty in having too much Vmem - as it needs to be handled. Practical experience: Running WinXP in 2GB RAM with 4GB of Vmem - works well for <50 megapixel images in Photoshop <= CS5. At 100 megapixel you're crawling - it may take an hour to just save the file.